# How to get customised date format for Notification expanded view

Tags: android

If i got a new message, in notification expanded view it shows only time. suppose If i got a message today(i.e on 06/06/2010) it should display simply a string "Today" and tomorrow it should show date on whilch message was received i.e it should display date 06/06/2010

Comment: [Don't](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/46035/should-i-remove-tags-that-dont-contribute-to-categorizing-the-question/46037#46037) [tag](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43879/anti-tags-valid-use-or-not) [not-programming-related.](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10216/can-we-disallow-the-use-of-belongs-on-xxxxxxx-and-not-programming-related-tag/10222#10222) @quintin

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to write a custom `DateFormat` object, and then call `DateFormat.format(Date)`

Answer (score 0):

If you have the date in milliseconds i.g.

```
long myDate = Calendar.getInstance().getTimeInMillis();
```

Otherwise you could get instance of calander and setTime

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat();
sdf.applyPattern(“MM/dd/yyyy”);
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
Date processDate = sdf.parse(“4/10/2007″);
calendar.setTime(processDate);
long myDate = calendar.getTimeInMillis();
```

Then you could take the difference of your date with the system date

```
String dateMessage = "today";
final int dayInterval = 86400000;
long difference = Calendar.getInstance().getTimeInMillis() - myDateInMillis;
if (difference > dayInterval)
    //dateMessage = format date MM/DD/YYYY...
```

From here you could update an ongoing notification to show the expected date value. See developer docs on [Creating a Custom Expanded View](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/notifications.html).

Note on updating notification.  If you have a custom expanded view. you can update TextViews by using Remoteview accessors..  The above link describes how to do this quite well.

```
RemoteViews contentView = new RemoteViews(getPackageName(), R.layout.custom_notification);
contentView.setTextViewText(R.id.text, mTitle);
```

Hope this helps.